# Drop in referral data due to HTTP, changed to HTTPS no recovery referral data since (in the last year)

Tags: google-analytics, https, referrer

We changed our site from HTTP to HTTPS about a year ago.

We have a static website, with no functionality for user input, so did not see it as an imperative to change to HTTPS anytime sooner, the reason we changed, is that we used to gets lots of Google Analytics refer data a few years ago in Google Analytics, but noticed more and more of the traffic being listed as "direct" we presumed that this was because the sites that where referring traffic to us had also made the switch to HTTPS.

Since the change we have NOT seen a recovery of Google Analytics referral data going forward.

I wonder if this is due to any older backlinks to our website being to the HTTP version rather than than HTTPS version, even though we 301 between them.

Would that be the case, and if so is there anyway we could fix it to get more referral data ?

Comment: Interesting question.    The only possibility that comes to mind would be implementing HSTS and getting your site onto the preload list.   That would force HTTPS such that most users would not ever hit the HTTP site even if they found a link to it.  I'm not sure if this would help with the referrer data or not though.  Perhaps somebody here has experience with that.

Comment: Thanks I was thinking about this some more, should i be able to see the referer data in the server log files ? (im not super familiar with them) Ive had a look at the raw data file and all i can see are for each request are the requesting IP, the HTTP status code of the request and the resource being requested. I would have though the principal problem was quite common as most sites 5-ish years ago would not have been HTTPS so they would have any links to their site to the HTTP version not the HTTPS version

Comment: "with no functionality for user input,"  This is not the only reason to use HTTPS. Both directions are to be protected: what users send to you (credit cards numbers, etc.) but also what you send to your users. Your site may be static but it can provide information that needs to be authenticated, making sure it really come from "you" and has not been tampered in transit. These 2 features (authentication and confidentiality/integrity) are what HTTPS brings to you.

Answer (score 2):

I just tested whether or not implementing HSTS and getting your site on the preload list would allow browsers to pass a referrer through a `http` link to your site.  Sadly it doesn't work.

Here is how I performed the test:

1. I found a `.dev` site with a PHP script that echos back the referrer.  I did this by searching google for `site:.dev HTTP_REFERER`.  Since the entire `.dev` top level domain is on the HSTS preload list, any `.dev` site with a script that shows the HTTP variables will work for testing.
2. I created a document on my `https` site with two links pointing to the `.dev` site with a dummy parameter to ensure no caching between clicks:

   ```
   <a href="https://example.dev/test/php/test.php?HTTPS">HTTPS link</a><br>
   <a href="http://example.dev/test/php/test.php?HTTP">HTTP link</a>
   ```
3. I opened the page in my browser and clicked on the two links.

Both Firefox and Chrome behaved the same way.  They passed the referrer on the HTTPS link but not on the HTTP link.    I was hoping that because HSTS automatically upgrades HTTP to HTTPS without over hitting your server, that the referrer policy would also automatically be updated.   It wasn't.

Because HSTS doesn't help, the only method I know for getting your referrer data back would be to contact all the sites and ask them to change their sites.  They could either change the links to your site to `https` or change their `Referrer-Policy` header to `unsafe-url`.

Answer (score 1):

The external HTTPS site would need to also update the backlink to link to your HTTPS site, otherwise if the link itself is still HTTP then the `Referer` header is not sent. Old backlinks probably have not been updated.

This has nothing to do with your HTTP to HTTPS redirect - which would otherwise pass the `Referer` (still user-agent dependent). The problem is that the `Referer` is probably not being sent in the initial request.

[HSTS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security) + [preload list](https://hstspreload.org/) (as mentioned in comments) *may* help with this as this *should* instruct the browser to upgrade the initial request (as if the backlink was already HTTPS) and thus permit the `Referer` to be sent. HSTS alone may not be sufficient, unless you have many repeat users that follow backlinks. Since HSTS (without being on the preload list) is only "remembered" by the browser after the user visits your HTTPS site the first time. **EDIT:** However, it seems from @Stephen's testing that this doesn't help after all!

Also note that websites today have a lot more control over the `Referer` that is sent if they implement the [Referrer-Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referrer-Policy). This allows sites to simply block the `Referer` on all outgoing requests if they so wish.

Answer (score -1):

Now that you have your site updated with HTTPS I would circle back around to the referring sites and ask to have the link updated to https (not a full fix but setting the right foundation).

The second factor to consider is if your site and referring sites may have been punished for not having HTTPS. My understanding (reading between the lines) is that Google will not reward unsecured sites regardless if users pass confidential information or not. So have the sites that were sending you traffic seen a decline in traffic over that same period? i.e., are there just less users to send you YoY?

Remember that users are going to hit a 'SITE UNSECURE -- TURN AWAY' page before being able to access an unsecured site.

I ask because if your referral traffic is down it may have more to do with the site referring you the traffic than your own per se, particularly if these sites didn't secure themselves.

My biggest advice though is that Google in my experience rarely backtracks, I wouldn't focus too much on regaining old referral traffic. Rather making the fixes that may have caused it, improving your security and user signals to benefit on the next uptick.

Comment: Your answer seems to indicate that you think this is a Google ranking problem.  It isn't.  It is a problem getting data in Google Analytics.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller I guess there should be clarification, it doesn't seem to me he's saying the data itself isn't populating but that the referral traffic from sites linking to him has declined (He assumes because of HTTPS) and it hasn't yet recovered after securing his site. In which case the question becomes how to "recapture" the lost referral traffic, my theory being determine if it's a referring source issue.

Comment: To confirm, it is not that the traffic has declined, but seems to have transferred from being "referral" traffic to "direct" traffic inside of GA.

Comment: I see, thanks for clarifying. In that case if the referring sites moved to HTTPS while you were on HTTP then the data would reported under direct. Secure websites that link to non-secure websites will not send referral data. Secondly, ensure users are only able to access the HTTPs version of your site so you don't lose any referral traffic.